# Redirect to previous page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have page1.aspx and page2.aspx.   In page1.aspx i have 4 ajax tabs ...   User clicks on 2nd tab and filters the data available using a list of checkbox. Now user goes to page2.aspx and performs some action. this page2.aspx has a back button and when user click on it page1.aspx should be loaded (this i have done). However there is a catch.  when we load page1.aspx as mentioned above i need to show the exact version (like data, selected tab, the items selected in checkbox list etc), of  page1.aspx (that was present before loading page2.aspx).   Can you give some basic idea on, how we can achieve this  ?

Answer (score 0):

On each operation on page1.aspx, store the state of control (checkbox,tab, filters, etc) in coockies , if you required it only for one session then you can store in sessions also.
And when you came back to page1.aspx restore the state from stored value. 
Below is a usefule link to learn about state persitance

[Persisting-the-state-of-a-web-page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7655/Persisting-the-state-of-a-web-page)

Comment: Please update your answer to include the gist of the code in the link. The link can die or change over time and then your answer won't be of use to anyone but if you add in some code here that provides even a broad overview of how to persist the state of a web page, then you'll end up helping a lot more people over a much longer time

Comment: I'll follow the link and try out my luck!! Will update the answer ASAP .